# how to set rate of ad-hoc wifi?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ad-hoc-network

I am trying to run a test and I want to set the data-rate on my laptop that is setup for Ad-Hoc mode. If I run `iwlist wlan0 bitrate` I get a `wlan0   unknown bit-rate information.` response.

Undeterred, I then ran `sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 11M` to attempt to lock the data rate to 11Mbps, but it doesn't not respond (just returns to the command prompt, no acknowledgement, and no errors).

My question is, is it possible to do this on Lucid Lynx?

I found a post on another forum from back in 2008 that someone was having a similar problem, in the end they said:

> I got the answers on my questions on bugzilla.  Not displayed rate is
>   not a problem of the driver: mac80211 does not display  rate for
>   ad-hoc network. Also I can't obviously increase rate with command 
>   'iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M' it must increases automaticaly after
>   applying some  patches that I need to find on bugzilla.

But they didn't post any links or followups, so I have no idea if they got it to work.

I tried updating my iw to 3.4-1 and then ran `sudo iw dev wlan0 ibss join SSIDname 2462 11:22:33:44:55:66 mcast-rate 11`, but I still don't get a rate response when I do the bitrate query.

Anyone know what I need to do to set/lock the rate while in ad-hoc mode?